# How to call onReceive method in another method?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Currently I developed a new method to discover bluetooh ready connections. Here is my code:

```
private void DiscoverOBDConnection() {
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    final List<String> discoverableDevicesList = new ArrayList<String>();

    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                short rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI, Short.MIN_VALUE);
                discoverableDevicesList.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress() + "\n" + rssi);

                String discoveredDeviceName = device.getName();
                discoverableDevicesList.add(discoveredDeviceName);
            }
        }
    };

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    context.registerReceiver(mReceiver,filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy
}
```

I just do not know how to call the onreceive method from another method. Could you help me to learn how to implement and discover the ready to connect bluetooth devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can just send broadcast

```
Intent i = new Intent(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Or call it directly

```
mReceiver.onReceive(this, new Intent(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
```

Comment: Soohwan, thank you for your answer. Could you edit my code to locate your answer? Where should I call BluetoothReceiver directly? Thank you.

Comment: Soohwan Park, it worked fine. I figured out how to implement your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Great. but why do you need to call it by your self? The broadcast is sent by the system @the_eternal